# How do I use Berkelium library in C++ code?

Tags: c++, include, berkelium

I want to use this library (https://github.com/sirikata/berkelium/downloads) with g++ compiler. It has 3 folders: bin, lib and include. What I do with files in each of the folder? And in my C++ code, do I need to use only headers in include folder? Thanks. I need to do this on g++ in Ubuntu 12.04 and I am not using any IDE just vi.
Edit: lib folder has a so file.

Comment: What compiler, IDE (if any) and platform are you using/targeting?

Comment: I need to so this on g++ in Ubuntu 12.04 and I am not using any IDE just vi.

Answer (score 0):

To compile programs with this library, you need to tell the compiler where are the include files, for object generation, and the library files for the linker job.

In one command line:

> g++ -I/path/to/berkelium/include -L/path/to/berkelium/library -o executable yourprogramname -llibberkerium

Answer (score 0):

I would go for https://developers.google.com/native-client/peppercpp/ , that library looks like it's just a wrapper and it's not officially supported.